# How to read csv files and converting specific lines into category columns - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import

The software I work with generates csv reports of items sold by seller, but there is a problema with its structure, as shown in the example below:

| Product | Quantity | Unit $ | Total $ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 - JOHN |  |  |  |
| 12551 | 1 | 5.00 | 5.00 |
| 14445 | 2 | 4.00 | 8.00 |
| 2 - JACK |  |  |  |
| 1200 | 5 | 2.00 | 10.00 |
| 00155 | 4 | 3.00 | 12.00 |

I want to import the csv and to create a new column with Seller information, but I don't know how to read the file, store seller information at second line, go through 'SELLER ' column and assign '1 - JOHN' to it until seller name changes to '2 - JACK'.

I expect to generate the following dataframe:

| Product | Quantity | Unit $ | Total $ | SELLER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12551 | 1 | 5.00 | 5.00 | 1 - JOHN |
| 14445 | 2 | 4.00 | 8.00 | 1 - JOHN |
| 1200 | 5 | 2.00 | 10.00 | 2 - JACK |
| 00155 | 4 | 3.00 | 12.00 | 2 - JACK |

I would appreciate so much any help you could give me.

Comment: Have you tried `pd.read_excel()` as a first step? You could read the entire file and then drop rows where "Quantity" is empty.

Comment: But in this case, how could I add the SELLER column with seller's information?

Comment: Have you read the file into a DataFrame? Post your code along with your current DataFrame.

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('Arquivos/df.csv', skiprows=1, sep=';')

|CODIGO |*TOTAL*  |UNITARIO| QTDE AV| CST.MED|
|----------|-----------|------------|-------------|-----------|
| 74 - ALESSANDRA| NaN |NaN| NaN |NaN
| 33883| 9,99 |9,99 |1.0 |3,33|
| 36496| 14,99| 14,99| 1.0| 4,99|
| 3710| 2,99| 2,99| 1.0| 2,01|
| 14 - AMANDA MOTA PASSOS| NaN |NaN |NaN |NaN|
| 1645 |12,5 |12,5 |0.0 |5,14|
| 33883 |19,98 |9,99 |2.0 |6,65|
| 35776 |12,99 |12,99 |1.0 |10,07|

Comment: Sorry for the mess. Lines with seller get NaN at other columns.

Comment: Do the `Seller` lines always start with this pattern: "1 - NAME1", "2 - NAME2"?

Comment: Exatly. A number, space, dash, space, name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try as follows:

- Create a boolean mask (`m`) with True for all "Sellers" using [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with a regex pattern (for an explanation, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/5A0oZX/1)).
- Use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with `m` as input and forward fill (using [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html)). Add to the `df` as column "Seller" by using [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html).
- Now, select from `df` only the rows for `m == False` using `[~m]` (unary operator `~` inverts the bools) and reset the index ([`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)).

**Code**

```
# assuming "Seller" entries follow pattern: "1 - NAME1", "2 - NAME2", etc.
m = df['Product'].str.contains('^\d+\s-\s')

out = df.assign(Seller=df['Product'].where(m).ffill())[~m].reset_index(drop=True)

out

  Product  Quantity  Unit $  Total $    Seller
0   12551       1.0     5.0      5.0  1 - JOHN
1   14445       2.0     4.0      8.0  1 - JOHN
2    1200       5.0     2.0     10.0  2 - JACK
3   00155       4.0     3.0     12.0  2 - JACK
```

If you are certain that one of the other columns will *always* contain `NaN` values, you can do this more easily. See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76914725/18470692) by [@not_speshal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9857631/not-speshal). But maybe with a csv file that is clearly flawed to begin with, you might want to play it safe.

**Used setup**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = """Product,Quantity,Unit $,Total $
"1 - JOHN",,,
"12551",1,5.00,5.00
"14445",2,4.00,8.00
"2 - JACK",,,
"1200",5,2.00,10.00
"00155",4,3.00,12.00"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))

df

    Product  Quantity  Unit $  Total $
0  1 - JOHN       NaN     NaN      NaN
1     12551       1.0     5.0      5.0
2     14445       2.0     4.0      8.0
3  2 - JACK       NaN     NaN      NaN
4      1200       5.0     2.0     10.0
5     00155       4.0     3.0     12.0
```

Comment: My God! Two lines of code and you solved my problem! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you get the first DataFrame after using `pd.read_csv`, try:

1. Since other columns are always `NaN` for a seller, you could use this to get a Series of seller names
2. `ffill` to create the "Seller" column
3. `drop` rows where Quantity is `NaN`

```
df["Seller"] = df["Product"].where(df["Quantity"].isna()).shift().ffill()
df = df.dropna(subset="Quantity")

>>> df
  Product  Quantity  Unit $  Total $    Seller
1   12551       1.0     5.0      5.0  1 - JOHN
2   14445       2.0     4.0      8.0  1 - JOHN
4    1200       5.0     2.0     10.0  2 - JACK
5   00155       4.0     3.0     12.0  2 - JACK
```

Comment: Incredible! Two lines of code and you solved my problem in a different, but equally efficient way. Thanks a lot, guys!